# SwiftMailer sending two different emails in succesion

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

This is NOT sending the same email to two recipients, but rather two different emails with one or two common elements.  I've done all kinds of manipulation but no matter what I've tried only the first email is sent.   Here's the code:

```
// cancellation confirmation emails
// common subject for both emails
$subject= "Dinner Reservation CANCELLATION";

require_once '../vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
// email to president
$body = "<br>" . $mbr_name . " has cancelled their dinner reservation for the " . $meeting_date . " meeting.<br>They held a reservation for " . $attending . ".";
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject)
    ->setTo(array($pres_email => $pres_name))
    ->setFrom(array('noreply@some.org' => 'Cancellation'))
    ->setBcc('webmaster@some.org')
    ->setBody($body, 'text/html');
$result = $mailer->send($message);

// email to member
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$body = "<br>This is to confirm the dinner reservation for member " . $mbr_name . " has been CANCELLED for the  " . $meeting_date . " meeting.<br><br>To make a new reservation log in to www.some.org and proceed as usual.";
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject . " confirmation." )
    ->setTo(array($mbr_email => $mbr_name))
    ->setFrom(array('noreply@some.org' => 'Some Org Dinner Cancellation'))
    ->setBody($body, 'text/html');
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this....

```
$info = array(
    'message_president' => "<br>" . $mbr_name . " has cancelled their dinner reservation for the " . $meeting_date . " meeting.<br>They held a reservation for " . $attending . ".",
    'message_member' => "<br>This is to confirm the dinner reservation for member " . $mbr_name . " has been CANCELLED for the  " . $meeting_date . " meeting.<br><br>To make a new reservation log in to www.some.org and proceed as usual."  
);


$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);   

//Create the message for the President
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject("Dinner Reservation CANCELLATION")
    ->setTo(array($pres_email => $pres_name))
    ->setFrom(array('noreply@some.org' => 'Cancellation'))
    ->setBcc('webmaster@some.org')
    ->setBody($info['message_president'],'text/html');

if ($mailer->send($message1){
    $message1_result = true;
}

//Create the message for the Member
$message2 = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject("Dinner Reservation CANCELLATION")
    ->setTo(array($mbr_email => $mbr_name))
    ->setFrom(array('noreply@some.org' => 'Some Org Dinner Cancellation'))
    ->setBody($info['message_member'],'text/html');

if ($mailer->send($message2){
    $message2_result = true;
}
```

**ADDED**

You may also want to look into the decorator plugin by swiftmailer

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html#decorator-plugin

**SECOND ADDITION**

I was reading that you may have better success with multiple emails defining the transport, although I know nothing about it really...but here are two examples, the second having consistent results being set to use smpt.

```
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smpt.server.tld', 25);
```

Comment: I get returns of 1 from echo($mailer->send($message) ) for the individual sends.  But I'll try your suggestion, regardless.  More afterward.

Comment: Doesn't work. $message2 is supplanted by $message and as a result, the same message is sent twice.  It's as if the newInstance() is not new after the upon the 2nd creation of newInstance().

Comment: Hmmm...this doesn't make sense. I edited my answer moving the send functions. And also setting the instance to NULL after the first send.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't make sense.  I accidentally sent $message twice instead of sending $message2 on the 2nd iteration.  Meanwhile, However, I fixed that and got the original result - i.e., first message rec'd by the BCC and 2nd message not received.   I'm going to try setting the $mailer to NULL, next - doesn't make sense either in light of developments, but can't hurt.

Comment: I can't make it send the 2nd message.  Next try is to put the 2nd message on a separate page.  Stay tuned...

Comment: Putting each email on a separate page AND a sleep(5) between them finally allowed both emails to go through.  Note that sleep() from 5 to 30 between emails on a single page did not work.

Comment: Wow, I am convinced this workaround shouldn't be needed. But I am glad you at least found a way for now. Have you looked into phpmailer? I have never run into these types of issues with it. It is always updated has standard mail() support, smtp support, ssl, batch sending and so on.  Might want to look into it :) https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: I was reading that there is no need to create another instance of the transport nor mailer, only the message. Have you tried it his way?

Comment: I added another bit to my answer regarding the transport, might be better setting it to smpt :)

Comment: My suspicion is that the 5 second sleep has something to do with godaddy's server.  I've had similar troubles simply using php mail() where the same code on the same page works sometimes and doesn't work other times.  At at still other times email sent with php mail() arrives hours later.  Regardless, I agree taht the workaround shouldn't be necessary, but I think I'm fed up with it.  So long as it's working I'm going to be finished with it.